# How to get Instagram access_token using OAuth2Swift

Tags: ios, swift, oauth-2.0, instagram-api

I tried every possible option, but the redirect URI does not return the `access_token`. I added a call back URI, I am able to ask from the user to login and give access permission, but I get this error on the call back.

I registered this URI on the Dev portal, and it seems to work fine:

```
http://oauthswift.herokuapp.com/callback/instagram
```

When I try to authenticate on a web browser using:

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=http://oauthswift.herokuapp.com/callback/instagram&response_type=token
```

I do get the access token:

[image: Access_Token]

When I try using `OAuthSwift`, I get this error and the redirect URI does not include the `access_token`, dispite what the Docs says:

[image: Docs]

This is the error:

> serverError[No access_token, no code and no error provided by server]

This is my code below:

```
 // MARK: Instagram
func doOAuthInstagram(_ serviceParameters: [String:String]){
    let oauthswift = OAuth2Swift(
        consumerKey:    serviceParameters["consumerKey"]!,
        consumerSecret: serviceParameters["consumerSecret"]!,
        authorizeUrl:   "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize",
        responseType:   "token"
    )

    let state = generateState(withLength: 20)
    self.oauthswift = oauthswift
    oauthswift.authorizeURLHandler = getURLHandler()
    let _ = oauthswift.authorize(
        withCallbackURL: URL(string: "http://oauthswift.herokuapp.com/callback/instagram")!, scope: "likes+comments", state:state,
        success: { credential, response, parameters in

            self.showTokenAlert(name: serviceParameters["name"], credential: credential)
            self.testInstagram(oauthswift)
        },
        failure: { error in
            print(error.description)
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: What did you register as callbackUrl on Instagram?

Comment: Hi @EridB The same as what I pass in `withCallBackURL` http://oauthswift.herokuapp.com/callback/instagram. I do get the call back to the app, but either `OAuth2Swift`, or the callback URI do not include the `access_token`, although when I try on a browser, it does.

Comment: The URL http://oauthswift.herokuapp.com/callback/instagram redirects you to `oauth-swift://oauth-callback/instagram`. Try to put the `oauth-swift://oauth-callback/instagram` directly as a callbackUrl and see what happens.

Comment: @EridB got an error that URI do not match the registered redirect URI. Found here https://github.com/OAuthSwift/OAuthSwift/wiki/API-with-only-HTTP-scheme-into-callback-URL that Instagram do not support an access token from the server, but need to be set up as an internalWebView. I did try to use this approach in the DemoApp in OAuthSwift, but this did not work, and I have no idea how to set this app :/

Comment: If I uncheck `Disable implicit OAuth` under *Security* for the client app on *Instagram*, registering `oauth-swift://oauth-callback/instagram` works fine on the OAuthDemo

Comment: @EridB were you able to register the URI on the Dev portal? Instagram only accepts `http://` URI's, this fails `oauth-swift://oauth-callback/instagram`

Comment: Sorry I meant `http://oauthswift.herokuapp.com/callback/instagram`

Comment: @EridB when you use this redirect URI, do you get the `access_token` using OAuth2Swift? the redirect URI works, but there is no access token on the turn callback.

Comment: Well I thought you were having trouble with the authentication. If your authentication shake it is okay, then on success access oauth object and retrieve the token this way: `oauth.client.credential.oauthToken`

Comment: And using `oauth.client` you can access the endpoints of `Instagram API` without providing anything else, as you're authenticated and OAuthSwift handles this for you.

Comment: This is where it goes wrong. Please read my post: The access token in Instagram is within the URL fragment. the redirect URI should return with the access_token, but when using an external browser, the access token is missing, when I use a browser with the URL, I can see the access_token, so the redirectURI and id do work. According to Instagram docs, the only way to access it is by using an internal WebView, but this does now work either. Were you actually able to retrieve Instagram access_token in any way using a client id?

Comment: @EridB on the callback, this fails as it cannot find the access_token `oauth.client.credential.oauthToken`

Comment: what if you use a webview delegate like they did here? https://github.com/OAuthSwift/OAuthSwift/wiki/API-with-only-HTTP-scheme-into-callback-URL  (note, i was trying to follow https://github.com/OAuthSwift/OAuthSwift/issues/258 but im guessing you already read those filed issues)

Comment: Hi @DavidT. thank you for your help. I tried we an internal web view, but for some reason, I was not able to enable this :/. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Hey, did you manage to take care of this problem? I'm struggling with github  api right now