# How to get a refresh token from Google YouTube Data API OAuth 2 iOS

Tags: ios, oauth, google-api, youtube-data-api

I am using `OAuthSwift` pod for Google API authentication. In the callback, the refresh token is missing. As Google is returning `500 Server Error`, when trying to ask for a new token after user already authenticated, I want to store the refresh token, and authorise the user the next time they login, and retrieve a new token.

This is my code:

```
           let callback = "\(Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier ?? ""):/oauth2Callback"
            _ = ytOAuth2Swift?.authorize(
                withCallbackURL: URL(string: callback)!,
                scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube", state: state,
                success: { credential, response, parameters in

                   print("YouTube Access_Token \(credential.oauthToken)")
                    print("YouTube efreshR_Token \(credential.oauthRefreshToken)")
                },
                failure: { error in
                    print("ERROR: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            )
```

This is the response we do get back!

[image: Response Parameters]

According to Google API docs, this is the response that should come in:

```
{
   "access_token":"1/fFAGRNJru1FTz70BzhT3Zg",
   "expires_in":3920,
   "token_type":"Bearer",
   "refresh_token":"1/xEoDL4iW3cxlI7yDbSRFYNG01kVKM2C-259HOF2aQbI"
}
```

I tried using an embedded `WebView` no luck:

[[image: mbedded WebView error messageE[2]]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well it looks like google API gave you refresh token once at the begining, and new requests doesn't give it anylonger. If yes you should know that refresh_token is only provided on the first authorization, so if you authorize more times it may not return the refresh_token again. Please try following instructions:

- Go to your account security settings: https://www.google.com/settings/u/1/security.
- Click the edit button next to "Authorizing applications and sites".
- Then click "Revoke Access" next to your app.

After it you next call should also return a refresh_token

It might be a bit different, because I do not use english language in my panel. When I was using refresh_token from google it never expires, you can use it forever to create new access_tokens.

**Another solution**

If it won't work, try  to set up in your code access_type as offline (I think easiest way is just to add a GET param in your API url as `access_type=offline`).

Necessary may be also `prompt=consent` in query. It will force user to authorize, and should then return refresh_token

More informations can be found in [Google Documentation: Oauth2](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline)

**Tip**

Good thing in Google API is that refresh_token never expires, until you wont revoke it or create a new one. So you can even hardcode it and use everytime you want to get a new access_token.

Comment: Hi @Karol, thank you for an awesome answer. I'm afraid that the only way I can develop, is to keep revoking access, otherwise it does not even give me `access_token` :D. I'll try the `access_type=offline` and let you know

Comment: Your welcome :) Anyway remember that refresh_token from Google never expires, so you can use it to get as many access_tokens as you want.

Comment: Hi @Karol , after revoking, and even creating a new Google App, the API return only 3 parameters excluding `refresh_token`, any suggestions? Many thanks

Comment: Strange. There always must be `access_type=offline` and also add `prompt=consent` in query. It will force user to authorize, and should then return `refresh_token`

Comment: You are a life saver @Karol !, `access_type` was the issue... I've been breaking my head around this for ages :D.. If you have time to help with a couple more questions, that would be really awesome! ;), I am trying to auth Instagram, 1) how to set an HTTP URI callback scheme http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40624790/what-url-scheme-to-use-with-an-http-redirect-callback-uri-oauth2-xcode
2), how to get the refresh token on the callback.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40591821/how-to-get-instagram-access-token-using-oauth2swift

Comment: Welcome :) I'm glad I could help :D

Comment: access_type=offline will only work for the first authorization, prompt=consent fixed the problem. thank you very much. The ChatGPT is not able to provide the correct answer at the moment. but your post fixed it.